# Distance to nearest cell with value "x"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, distance

I would like to create a raster where each cell equals the distance to the nearest cell >= the value of the source cell plus a constant. In the example below, the input raster has a grid size of 1m x 1m. Assume we are adding constant of 2 to the cells. For the top left cell, the distance to the nearest cell that contains a value >= 5+2 is 1.0m. I don't think any of the distance tools in ArcGIS will do this.

Input raster:

[image: Input raster]

Contant = 2

Output raster:

[image: Output raster]

Comment: Not the smartest here, but I would say that the GetCellValue (Raster tool), ArcGISPro or python/numpy could solve your problem.

Comment: Question: Input[0,0]=5 and its inmediate neighbor holds 8 (which is less than 5+2) then Output[0,0]=1. All good here. But Input[4,1]=5, then why Output[4,1]=1.4, same in Input[3,4]? If your cells are 1sqm, why you have decimals in your output?

Comment: @Delonix R. I'm not sure why that cell with the value 5 doesn't have a distance of 1 since it's neighbor on the left has a 9 (probably a misabstake), but the decimals are there because it's a euclidean distance and it's measuring a diagonal, so the cell adjacent on a diagonal is 1.4 (square root of 2).

Comment: Correct, karl. The answer for 5 in bottom row should be 1. It was late and I was getting tired!

Answer (score 1):

Assume input is intreger.

Take 1st value, 1 in above example.

A=Con(input GE 1+2, input)

B=Con(input==1, input)

D=EucDistance(A)

E=Con( is not null(B), D)

Save E. Proceed with next record

Mosaic saved rasters

Not sure why answer for 5 in bottom row != 1

It is very few lines of script in arcpy, run and go home

Comment: thank you FelixIP, I will try your suggestion and report back. I never thought to treat as a mosaic, good idea. The answer for 5 in bottom row should be 1. It was late and I was getting tired!

Comment: Hi @FelixIP or others, can you please provide additional detail to the expressions above? My python experience in non-existent, so syntax shortcuts have me confused.